# Is there a way to change all already uploaded images which are PNG and convert them to JPG?

Tags: images

I want to change all images that are already located on server from PNG to JPG. Now I know it could be maybe done the way to download all images convert to JPG and then to rewerite database to change all links from .png to .jpg but is there any other way? Because there is a lot of images.

Comment: try [smushit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)  plugin

Comment: The client initialy made it worse with this plugin. It actually deleted all the png and didnt make database relations to .jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this manually but if you are looking for a plugin solution:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/png-to-jpg/

Comment: I have tried the plugin you mentioned but it is not good for 40k images, but yes the plugin is good